# Bootstrap column order

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I've encountered a problem with bootstrap related with the stacking order.
Searched and saw many examples online, but it just won't work after convert it to my own code.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="container" style="border:1px solid red; ">
    <div class="row row-fluid">
       <div rel="1" style="border:1px solid black;" class="col-md-8 col-md-push-4">1</div>
       <div rel="2" style="border:1px solid black;" class="col-md-4 col-md-pull-8">2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is to show it like this:

### When at normal size, show:

### |1 : 2|

### When at small size, show:

### 2    |

### 1    |

I've checked some others's solution by adding pull and push, but it shows up like 2 | 1 by default without screen size changes. Where and what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Always remember that the basic structure of bootstrap is

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">Hi i am a coloumb</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">Hi i am a coloumb</div> 
   </div>
 </div>
```

You forgot the add the col-md , first , comes the "container" , Than the "Row" , than the "col-md" , 
inside the col-md put in the stuff you wanna fit in and in this case the page is divided into 2 equal coloumbs col-md-6 on each side[Out of a total of 12 ] , now at normal screen size you'll see both col-md's horizontal to each other , whereas when you make ur screen smaller , u'll see the same col-md's stacked vertically one after another .

check out the fiddle [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gautamz07/jC7af/8/)

Thats the magic of bootstrap , ur not programming anything to be responsive , ur just enclosing "everything u want to be responsive" in a "col-md" . and Voila ! everythings responsive .

I had given a similar answer to a different question on stack exchange . It might be helpful if you refer to it . below is the link

[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24962640/bootstrap-rows-and-columns-not-working/24963626#24963626)

Cheers.

Gautam.